# What courses should I take for Android Chat App

Tags: java, android, xml

I have leant basics of java, XML, firebase. I am able to create Instagram like app. But I want to proceed even further by enabling users to chat through the app (only major feature currently missing in my app). I have no idea as to where to start. Can anyone suggest a verified course which could help me learn?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this community is for specific questions on programming, not for curriculum advice.

Comment: Please revisit the [help] to learn how/what to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your further questions, I'm introducing you Google - your best friend, when you have a question and you are looking for the answer.

Some of good resurces (where I don't know where are you with your knowledge):

- thenewboston channel (youtube), help me a lot when I started learning Android development, they also provide good tutorials on other languages
- Udemy
- Coursera also has a lot of good resources

And a good advice, based on my experiences from work: start learning about Hybrid mobile technologies like React native, Ionic, Flutter, etc. because they are also very popular these days and I'm sure they will grow in future.